# Need help in Scrolling issue of android

Tags: android, listview

I am working on scrolling of listview.
I want to load data on scrolling of listview and i am doing like this:

```
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (loading) {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
            }
        } else {
            if ((totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + threshold)) {
                new loadMoreListView().execute();

                int currentPosition = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                View v = lv.getChildAt(0);
                int distFromTop = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();
                lv.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition, distFromTop);
            }
        }
    }
```

loadMoreListView is class which load data using AsynTask. 
My problem is when i come to the 10th position the listview starts loading data as expected but it freezes the whole listview. I cant interact with listview till data get loaded. Is there any solution to load data and interact with listview simultaneously.
Please don't suggest Endless Adapter or Prime. I already tried with that one.
Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set `loading = true` in else block?

Comment: For how long does the list freeze? Does the loadMoreListView really work asynchronously?

Comment: it freezes for near about 2-3 sec.

Comment: yes i have added loading= true

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LListviewsActivity extends Activity {
 ListView myList;
 Button getChoice;
 String[] listContent = {
        "January",
        "February",
         "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "September",
         "October",
        "November",
        "December"
};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
     getChoice = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getchoice);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
           android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,listContent);
    myList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    myList.setAdapter(adapter);
    getChoice.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       String selected = "";
              int cntChoice = myList.getCount();
              SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray =              
     myList.getCheckedItemPositions();
           for(int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++){
               if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                   selected +=                      myList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "\n";
               }
           } Toast.makeText(LListviewsActivity.this, selected          ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
      });
  }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this , it work

```
list_event.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if (scrollState != 0)
                eventAdapter.isScrollingEvent = true;
            else {
                eventAdapter.isScrollingEvent = false;
                eventAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
```

write boolean isScrollingEvent=true
and your adapter is liake eventAdapter

Check this link it is very use-full 
[List View Scroll Not Smooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054465/list-view-scroll-not-smooth/22558955#22558955)