# Android smoothScrollTo isn't smooth

Tags: android, scrollview, smooth-scrolling

I'm trying to scroll to a given layout in a ScrollView. My XML is basically composed of a ScrollView implementing various RelativeLayout and I want to programatically scroll to a given one.

I have the following code in my Activity's onCreate method :

```
// Defining my view
sv = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.reward_scroll_view);

// Get Layout's id from intent
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    idToScroll = extras.getInt("uiToScroll");
    sv.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            // Scroll to the passed element
            RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(idToScroll);
            sv.smoothScrollTo(0, layout.getTop());
        }
    });
}
```

The "auto-scroll" to a given anchor is working but there is no "smooth" effect, just a raw scroll to the layout. What am I missing ?

Comment: I am curious where do you do this? onResume()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem thanks to **Aamir**'s comment, here is how my final code looks like :

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {

        // Get Layout's id from intent
        idToScroll = extras.getInt("uiToScroll");
        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(idToScroll);

        // Start 1 second timer
        new CountDownTimer(1000, 20) {      
             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                 // Nothing...
             }

             // When over, start smoothScroll
             public void onFinish() {  
                 sv.smoothScrollTo( 0, layout.getTop() );  
             }      
        }.start(); 
    }
```

My view may have just need some delay to display the scroll effect properly.

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding post method of view.

Scroll view not working smoothly with in UI Thread or Post

[Look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054465/list-view-scroll-not-smooth)

Comment: Thanks but what should I do then ? If I remove the runnable, the scroll doesn't even apply.

Comment: Thanks again for the link but I don't think it is related to my situation since I'm not loading my content dynamically. All the components of my ScrollView are hard-coded and I just want a smooth anchor scroll effect to a specific component.

Comment: Then Use countdown timer. It will show your scroll movement smoothly